# jenkinsfile задание переменных окружения

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Пытаюсь в jenkinsfile прописать путь для логов

```
def a = '~/${env.JOB_NAME}/${env.TIMESTAMP}'
```

но при вызове echo(a) получаю '~/${env.JOB_NAME}/${env.TIMESTAMP}'

Вроде форматирование строк выполняется правильно. Не подскажете, где ошибка?

Comment: как минимум: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6761498/4827341

Comment: спасибо
shame on me

Answer (score 2):

проблема ковычек, нужны двойный, тогда все ок

```
def a = "~/${env.JOB_NAME}/${env.TIMESTAMP}"
```